# save_uploaded_file in php is not working despite the code not having errors

Tags: php, xampp, backend, web-development-server

I'm running xampp php server on kali linux. I tried saving a file I uploaded via POST method and its not working. Can someone see the error?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

//explode from panctuation
$tempExtension = explode('.', $name);
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($tempExtension));

$isAllowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

if (in_array($fileExtension, $isAllowed)) {
    //zero is no error 1 is error
    if ($error === 0) {
        if ($size < 100000) {
            $newFileName = uniqid('',true) . "." . $fileExtension;
            $fileDestination = "uploads/" . $newFileName;
            move_uploaded_file($newFileName, $fileDestination);
            header("Location: index.php?uploadedsuccessfully");
        }else{
            echo "Your size is too big";
        }
    }else{
        echo "There was an error. Try again";
    }
} else{
    echo "Your file type is not accepted";
}
```

}
?>

Comment: The first thing to check is the form encoding: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: "Not working" is really not a smart thing to say here. That tells us nothing about what actually happens. Do you get any of these error messages you are trying to echo there, if so, which one? If not, then start by verifying which if/else branches it goes into, starting from the very top one, by making some debug outputs.

Comment: The file is not being saved. Even if I try to work with writing into text file and they can't be created or saved.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the upload folder permission, It should be 777
or check the apache2 error log for more details

Comment: Folder permissions should generally be 755, and file permissions 644. 777 gives anyone permission to do anything, which is a big security risk. https://linuxhandbook.com/chmod-command/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).